# Can I use vsftpd over WWW for free?

Tags: networking, ftp, vsftpd

I have used vsftpd to share files over a local network on my Ubuntu 15.04. Its very elegant an I like it very much.

I have seen many websites using ftp over the WWW. For example [suse](ftp://ftp.suse.com/%22suse%22)  and [debian](ftp://ftp.debian.org) and many more.

My question is : Can I use ftp to share files over the internet without spending any money ? If yes,then how? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

You can if the following prerequisites are met:

1. You have a static IP address from your ISP
2. You know how to properly configure your firewall and port forwarding
3. You know how to properly configure ftpd so that you're not opening yourself up to quite as much of a security risk.

If any one of those fails then you can't do it.  If I were you, I would get [DropBox](https://db.tt/CTUrE5tR) (yes it's a referral link, so you will get free bonus space) and use that to share files.  DropBox is much simpler to use and is also very secure.

If you are dead set on hosting it from your own network, then you might want to consider the costs:

1. In America, to get a static IP usually costs about 3 times more than a normal internet connection.
2. By running ftp on that connection, you open up a huge security risk.
3. Your ISP probably has a cap on how much upstream data you can use, so you'll likely run out of data much faster.

Now if you're still set on hosting it yourself, then I would recommend apache2 rather than ftp.  Apache is a http server instead of an ftp server, and it's much more secure.  More information on apache can be found on the [Apache HTTP server project documentation page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/).

Please, take my advice, don't try to host this yourself, especially with ftp.  You're opening up a  can of worms that will take eons to close again.